# WCF Channel: Server not responding after 10 minutes

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I created an architecture formed by a client and a server those communicates on a WCF Channel in localhost, all works fine, but if there is no activity (requests from client) between the two ones for more than 10 minutes the server doesn't respond anymore. The connection is still alive but simply server is not responding to client request, so the client must disconnect and reconnect for being able to send request to the server. Maybe I let some parameters slip.

The address I used is: net.tcp://localhost:8080/ICS;
Channel type: duplex;

Comment: Take a look at `inactivityTimeout` and `receiveTimeout`.

Comment: Yes it seems that this is the problem. I found this article http://www.rauch.io/2015/06/25/all-wcf-timeouts-explained/ where all the timeouts are explained, and well the timeout for Inactivity and Receiving are 10 minutes.

Comment: Is the problem that the service operation is not returning within a reasonable time, or that you know the service operation is long-running but the caller is timing out?

Comment: The operations are quite short (few seconds) and without inactivity the system works for days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in `receiveTimeout`. The service host uses this timeout to determine when to drop idle connections. If no message is received within the configured time span the connection is closed. By default it is 10 minutes.

Comment: inactivity timeout only relevant when you're using WCF support for WS-ReliableMessaging. There in nothing in the OPs question to suggest that they are. Additionally, receive timeout is a consumer-side setting and has no effect on the service side, where the problem appears to be in the OPs case.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `receiveTimeout` is not consumer-side setting. And I also added `inactivityTimeout` there because there are some dependencies and both should be aligned because some combinations does not make sense.

Comment: Update, ReliableMessaging is disabled therefore edit InactivityTimeout makes no sense as Tom Redfern said. Whereas changing ReceiveTimeout parameter of my binding settings solves the problem.

Comment: @Lepijohnny you're in fact correct. Apologies for my fallacious assertion regarding recieveTimeout. Please edit your question to reflect and I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Update, `ReliableMessaging` is not enabled therefore edit `InactivityTimeout` makes no sense

Whereas changing `ReceiveTimeout` parameter of my binding settings solves the problem.

My code:

```
var bind = new NetTcpBinding();                   // my binding instance
var relSessionEnabled = bind.ReliableSession.Enabled;            // this is false
var inactivityTimeout = bind.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout;  // this is 10 minutes
bind.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;          // this was 10 minutes before this instructuion
```